# Variable in getElementById

Tags: javascript

I need to go over all radio buttons of the form and paint the td that contain the checked ones.
Cant pass the variable of the TD id, in the loop (aca):

```
function veamos() {

    var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {

           if (allElems[i].type === 'radio' && allElems[i].checked) {

           var aca="pinta"+i;

                document.getElementById(aca).style.backgroundcolor = '#9e0000';

           } else {
            //document.getElementById(estetd).style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
           }        
        }       
}
```

document.getElementById('pinta1').style.backgroundColor = '#9e0000', seems to work... cant build the variable to loop all form

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `backgroundcolor` => `backgroundColor`

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do there sir?

Comment: @gdoron It looks like he's trying to color the background of another element based on the index of certain checked radio buttons.

Comment: @ZoltanToth. Wrote it as an answer.

Comment: @TheZ. In a **very** spaghetti way... :(

Comment: @gdoron Yeah, it's a bit unsavory to try and select them based on a returned search index... I tend to try and overlook bad form when answering a question that is unrelated xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question right I think you have 2 options.

```
function veamos () {
  var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0, len = allElems.length; i<len; i++) { /* do not use .length in the loop condition, that will have very bad performance on element arrays returned by getElementsByTagName. */
    var elem = allElems[i];
    if (elem.type==='radio') {
       /* Option 1: This depends on the HTML structure, where is the TD in relation to the input? */
       var td = elem.parentNode; /* if it is 2 levels up then use elem.parentNode.parentNode */
       /* Option 2: This depends on having an ID on the <input> and <td> that are similar, like this <input id="r1"> <td id="r1TD"> */
       var td = document.getElementById(elem.id + 'TD');
       td.style.backgroundColor = elem.checked ? '#9e0000' : '#ffffff';
       /* I would recommend using a class name (CSS) instead of using a hard coded color! */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Javascript is case sensitive. Change

```
document.getElementById(aca).style.backgroundcolor = '#9e0000';
```

to

```
document.getElementById(aca).style.backgroundColor = '#9e0000';
```

...

**UPDATE** See a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPy9f/)

Comment: Seems like the variable "aca" is not being passed.

Comment: @user1487091. Maybe you should try debug the code first... SO isn't a debugging service!

Comment: @user1487091: It seems more like `aca` contains the ID of an element which does not exist.

Comment: <td id="pinta1" class="answer">
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="36336X1X1SQ001" value="A2" id="answer36336X1X1SQ001-A2" title="Bueno" onclick="javascript:veamos();" />
</td>

Comment: document.getElementById('pinta1').style.backgroundColor = '#9e0000', seems to work... cant build the variable to loop all form

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
document.getElementById(aca).style.backgroundcolor = '#9e0000';
```

should be

```
allElems[i].style.backgroundcolor = '#9e0000';
```

Comment: Need to colour the TD that contains the radio button. <td id="pinta1">